# Утечка памяти в виджете Text в TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня в программе используется виджет Text, в который выводиться текст. В виджете текст очищается с помощью `text.delete`, когда это надо. Проблема заключается в том, что при отчистке Text, текст в нем очищается, но память, потребляемая программой не уменьшается. То есть, когда текст выводиться, программа потребляет память, когда удаляется - память не освобождается. В итоге количество потребляемой памяти моей программой растет.

Вот ситуация, по которому я убедился, что память не освобождается, и что в этом вина виджета Text:

```py
from tkinter import *

class TextBox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = Text()
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    
    def println(self, text):
        self.text.insert(END, text + "\n")

    def clear(self):
        self.text.delete("1.0", "end")

root = Tk()
textBox = TextBox()

root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: textBox.println("Какой-то текст" * 1000))
root.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda event: textBox.clear())

root.mainloop()
```

Для удобства я создал класс TextBox. Если в примере зажать на несколько секунд Enter для вывода текста, а затем BackSpace для его полного удаления, то память не освободиться
(Количество потребляемой памяти я смотрю в диспечере задач).

Есть способы, чтобы используемая память виджетом Text после каждой очистки текста освобождалась?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете периодически вызывать метод gc.collect() из модуля gc (garbage collector) для явного запроса на сборку мусора, что может помочь освободить неиспользуемую память. Важно отметить, что это не всегда гарантирует мгновенное освобождение памяти, но может снизить накопление её неиспользуемой части в вашей программе.

Вот как вы можете модифицировать ваш код для включения вызова gc.collect():

```
from tkinter import *
import gc  # Импортируем модуль gc

class TextBox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = Text()
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    
    def println(self, text):
        self.text.insert(END, text + "\n")
        gc.collect()  # Вызываем сборщик мусора после вставки текста

    def clear(self):
        self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
        gc.collect()  # Вызываем сборщик мусора после очистки текста

root = Tk()
textBox = TextBox()

root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: textBox.println("Какой-то текст" * 1000))
root.bind("<BackSpace>", lambda event: textBox.clear())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!